# safest apache/mysql/php combo distro?

Tags: web-hosting

I'm gonna run a public site on my Win XP and wonder what apache/mysql/php distro I should use. Is it ok to use wamp? or is that just for local developing? would it be safe to have it open for public?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are several packages that instal Apache+MySQL+PHP onto Windows, that refer to themselves as WAMP, so you'll have to be specific about which one you mean (I suggest adding a link to it in your question) before you can get a specific answer.

More generally, in terms of "safe" you need to be sure that the package gets timely security updates when they are released by the relevant projects (and that you install said updates when they become available). You can gauge how good a package is at integrating security updates by comparing its history/changelog against those of similar packages and/or of the applications that they install.

If you are unsure about the update policy of the projects that package Windows versions of these utilities, you might be better off running a know-good (in terms of security patch policy) Linux distribution in a VM on your machine and making sure you get updates regularly (i.e. with "aptitude update && aptitude upgrade" under Debian or Ubuntu) - though this requires a little Linux knowledge. You could also maintain the Apache+PHP+MySQL packages yourself - IIRC all three have official Windows binary releases so you'll not need to compile from source unless you want unusual options.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the safest distribution for this kind of solutions, you should use OpenBSD, but it's an advanced user distribution.

I think Linux (Debian or Ubuntu) could be a good alternative if you don't feel fine with BSD.

Answer (score 0):

It is as safe as you configure it to. *You* are responsible for your server, so you must check the settings for Apache, PHP and MySQL anyway.

Do you really want to use Windows XP for a public server? MS bashing aside, it's a desktop OS, not a server OS.

I don't know about WAMP, but since it supports multiple versions of Apache, MySQL and PHP, you should be able to use the latest builds with all security patches.